# Permission denied: '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil'

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, permissions

I'm trying to install a package on my macbook, but I get this error. I already tried to give the map acces with chmod. What can I do to fix this?

Thnx!

```
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil'
```

Comment: [This (unrelated) bug](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/426) seems to indicate that you should try avoid installing packages to `/System/Library` -- there is a workaround listed there as well that may help -- **obligatory warning:** I'm not a mac user, so take this with a grain of salt.

Comment: You an administrator? And are you trying to install a third-party package?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using pip or easy_install on a Mac. You need to use sudo pip install. However, it's not a good idea because it may mess up your Mac's python configuration. The best practice is to create a virtual environment with virtualenv (Google it) then install the module inside of that virtual environment. Since it's a virtual environment you do not need to use sudo to install packages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pip install --user scikit-learn` or try `sudo -H pip install scikit-learn` but I would rather use Virtual Envrionment instead of previous 2 options, cause it's more easy and safe. After launching virtualenv just type `pip install scikit-learn` and it should work.